# Is length extension attack considered as collision?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, length-extension

I came across a few articles about length extension attacks on cryptographic hash functions. I was very surprised to read that SHA-256 and SHA-512 are prone to length extension attacks. This seems contradictory to the fact that—to the best of my knowledge—there are no known collisions on these algorithms.

According to the [comparison of SHA functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2#Comparison_of_SHA_functions) table from Wikipedia the *capacity
against length extension attacks* is 0 for both SHA-256 and SHA-512 which should mean that this attack does not require much computing resources.

Aren't length extension attacks considered as collisions as well?

Comment: Length extension attacks are conditional collisions. So assuming you know one collision, the length extension attack allows you to construct arbitrarily many out of that one.

Comment: Can you define _conditional collision_? Does _assuming you know one collision_ mean that the length extension attack is still impractical for SHA-2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No**, the length extension attack/property is not considered a collision. It does not allow to build a collision.

The length extension property is that given the hash of a bitstring $M$ of given length $l$ (but arbitrary and unknown content), it is possible to compute the hash of $M\mathbin\|F(l)\mathbin\|E$ with $F(l)$ a short bitstring deduced from the length of $l$, and any known bitstring $E$.

It follows that if messages $M$ and $M'$ of the same length collide (have the same hash even though $M\ne M'$), then $M\mathbin\|F(l)\mathbin\|E$ and $M'\mathbin\|F(l)\mathbin\|E$ also collide. Therefore, the length extension property eases building more collisions from an existing collision among messages of the same length.

MD5, SHA-1, SHA-256, SHA-512 have the length extension property (and correspondingly, it is used to extend MD5 and SHA-1 collisions). SHA-3 and SHA-512/256 do not have the length extension property, because enough of the internal state does not make it to the output. The situation is not clear cut for other SHA-2 hashes truncated to more than half their internal state size (e.g. SHA-224 has only 32 bits of resistance to length extension).